# Why won't my xpath work?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prefix:someName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:prefix="someUri" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation.xsd">
        <prefix:someName2>
            ....
        </prefix:someName2>
    </prefix:someName>
```

And my code looks like this:

```
private Node doXpathThingy(Document doc) {
     final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

     XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

     xPath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext(){
        @Override
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Null prefix");
            }

            return doc.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
     });

    try {
        XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(xpathString);
        return (Node)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ....        }
}
```

I'm trying to get this to work with any valid xpath. It works with these xpaths:

"prefix:someName"

"."

But NOT with: "prefix:someName2". It returns null.

I guess I'm still not getting something about namespaces, but I don't understand what? I've tried leaving out the prefixes from my xpath but then nothing works at all.
I've also checked if the correct uri is returned for the prefix at doc.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix), and it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query `prefix:XXX` means `child::prefix:XXX`, that is, find an element child of the context node whose name is `prefix:XXX`. Your context node is the document node at the root of the tree. The document node has a child named `prefix:someName`, but it doesn't have a child named `prefix:someName2`. If you want to find a grandchild of the document node, try the query `*/prefix:someName2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. My problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't say I'm familiar with the Java way of doing XPath, but it looks like you are making an XPath query from the root of the document, so what you are seeing is the expected behavior.

Try this to find someName2 anywhere in the doc

`//prefix:someName2`

or this to find it as the child of someName2

`/prefix:someName/prefix:someName2`

or this to find it as the direct child of any root element

`/*/prefix:someName2`

Comment: Thank you, this works! I thought there was something wrong with my code when it was in fact my lack of knowledge about xpath syntax that was the problem.